# ModuleNotFoundError with importlib.import_module for submodule

Tags: python, oop, modulenotfounderror, python-importlib

(my english is really bad sorry)

I write a OOP code and I want a main file who import (auto with importlib) some "templates" to execute. Every templates have a "main file" and others objects for a good oriented programmation. BUT I can't import my "main module" beacause importlib raise ModuleNotFoundError directly on import object at the beginning code (example below).
Please help ! I try to resolve with inspect lib and ModuleFinder lib or force at parsing my file name in os.listdir but... nothing... I'm totally blocked.

```
--main.py
--templates/
---__init__.py
---Beer/
----__init__.py
----Beer.py
----Livraison.py
```

main.py

```
...
def import_templates(package, recursive=True):
    if isinstance(package, str):
        print(package)
        package = import_module(package)
        print('1 : ' + str(package))
    results = {}
    for loader, name, is_pkg in walk_packages(package.__path__):
        full_name = package.__name__ + '.' + name
        results[name] = import_module(full_name)
        if recursive and is_pkg:
            results.update(import_templates(full_name))
    return results
...
```

Beer.py

```
...
from Livraison import Livraison
...
```

output terminal

```
templates
1 : <module 'templates' from 'PATH/GestionEmbed/templates/__init__.py'>
templates.Beer
1 : <module 'templates.Beer' from 'PATH/GestionEmbed/templates/Beer/__init__.py'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH/GestionEmbed/main.py", line 59, in <module>
    tmp = import_templates("templates")
  File "PATH/GestionEmbed/main.py", line 45, in import_templates
    results.update(import_templates(full_name))
  File "PATH/GestionEmbed/main.py", line 43, in import_templates
    results[name] = import_module(full_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "PATH/GestionEmbed/templates/Beer/Beer.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Livraison import Livraison
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Livraison'
```

Thank you in advance if you can help me (and again sorry for my english ^^)

Answer (score 1):

You are running `main.py`, which imports `Beer.py`, which tries to import `Livraison.py`.

The problem is the line in `Beer.py` which says: `from Livraison import Livraison`. Python tries to import `Livraison` based on the position of `main.py` - so it is like you wrote `from Livraison import Livraison` in `main.py`. There is no `Livraison.py` in the same folder as `main.py`, so there is an error.

To import based on the position of `Beer.py`, use:

```
from .Livraison import Livraison
```

in `Beer.py`.

The `.` means that python imports `Livraison` based on the position on `Beer.py`

Comment: Thank you veryyyy much ! I feel a little stupid now... But thank you ! You're my God !